# How to create a semicircle sphere in three.js

Tags: three.js

I am new to three.js and I am trying to create a hemisphere, like half of the sphere. However, I can’t seem to find the geometry for it. Do you need to create a custom shape and how do you do so?

I want to create a hemisphere like this:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

THREE.SphereGeometry has 4 arguments on the constructor that you can use to assign the latitude and longitude at which the sphere starts and ends: `phiStart, phiEnd, thetaStart, thetaEnd`. You can see it [in action on the official documentation page](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/SphereGeometry).

Here's a demo below:

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,  1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 50;

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
    canvas: document.querySelector("#canvas")
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

// Half a sphere
const phiStart = 0;
const phiEnd = Math.PI * 2;
const thetaStart = 0;
const thetaEnd = Math.PI / 2;

const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 15, 32, 16, phiStart, phiEnd, thetaStart, thetaEnd );
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x9900ff, wireframe: true } );
const sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( sphere );

function animate() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

animate();
```

```css
html, body { margin:0; padding:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script><script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Just by curiosity, is it possible to make the sphere solid? It seems that the OP idea is that of a solid semi-sphere.

Comment: @adelriosantiago Yes, it is possible by using a different material. I chose wireframe to focus on the geometry.

Comment: @Marquizzo thanks alot mate, is there anyway to make it such that the hemisphere is at the bottom?

Comment: @stackoverflownumba1 I gave you the four variables and [a link to the live working demo](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/SphereGeometry)! Play around with the `phiStart, phiEnd, thetaStart, thetaEnd` sliders in the demo to learn what each one of them does, and I'm certain you'll arrive at the solution you're looking for :) Just keep in mind `Math.PI` is half a circle, and `Math.PI / 2` is a quarter circle. Good luck!

Comment: @Marquizzo thanks i figured out, u can change the thetastart to 1.5 to flip it to btm

Comment: @stackoverflownumba1 There you go!